# Add data to another table

Tags: excel, vba

i have a table("table1") in one sheet.i have a button that adds the data in the table to another table in another sheet("table").every time its overriding the data.
i want to add the data("table1") to the table("table2") instead of overriding it.
this is the code:

```
 Sheets("Letter (P V)").ListObjects("Table1").Range.Copy _
      Destination:=Sheets("Actual").Range("E2")
```

thanks!

Comment: find the last row in the target range and add it there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba

Comment: Does the `Actual` sheet also hold a `ListObject`? If so then you can just get ahold of that table and get a reference to a new row with `ListObject.ListRows.Add`, which returns the `ListRow` object for the row that's been added at the bottom of the table; pasting to that row's `Range` should "just work".

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rangeToPaste As Range
Set ws = Sheets("Actual")
'go up from the bottom to the first row populated in column 5(E) after do +1 to paste after the last row'
Set rangeToPaste = ws.Range("E" & ws.Cells(ws.rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).row + 1)
Sheets("Letter (P V)").ListObjects("Table1").Range.Copy Destination:=rangeToPaste
```